# How to read the communication between spaceships in Excession?

Tags: iain-m-banks, the-culture

In [Iain M. Banks's *Excession*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excession), there are several discussions between spaceships that are in a format that looks like a log file. It looks like this:

> (GCU Grey Area signal sequence file #n428857/119)
>   .
>   [swept-to-tightbeam, M16.4, received@n4.28.857.3644]
>   xGSV Honest Mistake 
>   oGCU Grey Area 
>   Take a look at this:
>
> oo
>
> (Signal sequence #n428855/1446, relay:)
>
> oo
>
> 1) [skein broadcast, Mclear, received @ n4.28.855.0065+]:
>   *!c11505* 
>   oo
>
> 2) [swept beam Ml, received @ n4.28.855.0066-]: SDA.
>   C2314992+52
>   xFATC @ n4.28.855.
>
> oo
>
> 3) [swept beam, M2, relay, received@ n4.28.855.0079-]:
>   xGCU Fate Amenable To Change.
>   oGSV Ethics Gradient
>   & as requested:
>   Significant developmental anomaly.
>   C4629984+523
>   (@n28.855.0065.43392).

And so on...

Is there a cheat sheet or something that could help me to extract all the information contained in the headers and other sections of those discussions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turn out it's all explained later in the book.

Comment: that's typical.